# integration of mapbox in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just using mapbox in unity and facing a problem. Recently i am using unity 2017.3.1f1 and mapbox unity-sdk_v1.4.0 and follow the following link for integration of mapbox in unity [ http://www.yudiz.com/design-your-map-in-mapbox-and-integrate-it-in-unity-part-1/]

but when i write the c# script for PlayerTileProvider it gives me the following error.

Assets/Scripts/TransformTileProvider.cs(26,28): error CS0507: `TransformTileProvider.OnInitialized()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding`public' inherited member `Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractTileProvider.OnInitialized()'

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mapbox.Unity.Utilities;
using Mapbox.Unity.Map;
using Mapbox.Utils;
using Mapbox.Map;

public class PlayerTileProvider : AbstractTileProvider {

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform locationMarker;

    [SerializeField]
    private AbstractMap map;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _visibleBuffer;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _disposeBuffer;

    private bool _initialized = true;
    private Vector2d _currentLatLng;
    private UnwrappedTileId _currentTile;
    private UnwrappedTileId _cachedTile;

    void Start() {
        Initialize (map);
    }

    internal override void OnInitialized() {
    }

    float _elapsedTime;

    [SerializeField]
    float _updateInterval;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if ( !_initialized ) return;

        _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_elapsedTime >= _updateInterval)
        {
            _elapsedTime = 0f;
            _currentLatLng = locationMarker.position.GetGeoPosition ( map.CenterMercator, map.WorldRelativeScale );

            _currentTile = TileCover.CoordinateToTileId ( _currentLatLng, map.Zoom );

            if ( !_currentTile.Equals ( _cachedTile ) ) 
            {
                for ( int x = _currentTile.X - _visibleBuffer; x <= (_currentTile.X + _visibleBuffer); x++ ) 
                {
                    for ( int y = _currentTile.Y - _visibleBuffer; y <= (_currentTile.Y + _visibleBuffer); y++ ) 
                    {
                        AddTile ( new UnwrappedTileId ( map.Zoom, x, y ) );
                    }
                }
                _cachedTile = _currentTile;
                Cleanup ( _currentTile );
            }
        }
    }

    private void Cleanup( UnwrappedTileId currentTile ) {
        var count = _activeTiles.Count;
        for ( int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            var tile = _activeTiles[i];
            bool dispose = false;
            dispose = tile.X > currentTile.X + _disposeBuffer || tile.X < _currentTile.X - _disposeBuffer;
            dispose = dispose || tile.Y > _currentTile.Y + _disposeBuffer || tile.Y < _currentTile.Y - _disposeBuffer;

            if ( dispose ) {
                RemoveTile ( tile );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me why this error appear

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1st, is the code you posted the script named "TransformTileProvider.cs"?
2nd, as the error indicates, cannot change access modifiers when overriding public inherited member `Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractTileProvider.OnInitialized()"
that mean that you need to keep the access modifier of "internal override void OnInitialized()" to the original which I assume is public?

Comment: hey sorry for late reply . As you say i made it public and that error was gone but after that many other error appear and there is also so many option missing in my inspector panel that are followed in that link tutorial. i just wanna simply achieve that features which are covered in tutorial

Comment: like i didn't find vector tile factory option in inspector panel of mapbox and i also didnt find map type to add custom map in map image factory

Comment: there is also error in PlayerTileProvider.cs Assets/Mapbox/Unity/Map/PlayerTileProvider.cs(55,42): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Mapbox.Map.TileCover.CoordinateToTileId(Mapbox.Utils.Vector2d, int)' has some invalid arguments Assets/Mapbox/Unity/Map/PlayerTileProvider.cs(55,81): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `float' expression to type `int'